# Why am I not able to comment on my own posts?

Tags: support

I am getting started on the Blender Stack Exchange site and have asked a complicated question and am getting great answers. But I am told need 50 points to comment on answers. How do I deal with this?

Comment: It sounds like you may have two accounts. If you have a question that you posted, you should *always* be able to comment on the question and answers, regardless of your reputation. This is not possible if you're not logged in to the same account you created the question with, however. Do you have access to the computer/device you originally posted the question with? Or a link to the question you can [edit] into your question here?

Comment: The relevant info has been edited into the FAQ, so this is now a duplicate. Please note that it's policy to close questions as duplicates of FAQs even if they're merely related, and even if the information wasn't contained in the FAQ at the time the question was asked. This is to direct all users to the canonical source containing the relevant info.

Comment: @Ano No, that's certainly no duplicate, but an exceptional situation.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ I added that text because I've seen one other case where this exact situation happened, so all of those can be closed as duplicates.

Answer (score 6):

It looks that you managed to create 2 different accounts accidentially

https://blender.stackexchange.com/users/53050/dick-meehan

and

https://blender.stackexchange.com/users/53255/dick-meehan

You always can comment on your own posts and its answers, but since you are logged in with your other account you cannot comment anymore.

I'd recommend you should ask to merge these 2 accounts. [Here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/18232/how-can-one-link-merge-combine-associate-two-accounts-users-anonymous) is a detailed description of the steps how to do so.

Answer (score 6):

You can actually always comment on a question you've asked or the answers on it, regardless of your reputation. Unfortunately, it looks like you have two accounts, if the question you're talking about is this one: [Earthquake visualization in blender?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/101950/earthquake-visualization-in-blender)

As such, you can't comment with this account because it doesn't recognize it as your question. To fix this, you'll need to request that your accounts be merged by going to the "[contact](https://blender.stackexchange.com/contact)" link in the footer. You really want to do this and make sure you're logged in and registered and have all of your rep in one place and so that you can respond to the people asking you questions.